# Custom Directive is not working with div id

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive called packageHeader, When the user scrolls through the list, the header must show at top of the list until the next one is reached. It's working with only window element not with div id, here i'm attaching the **html**

```
<div id="list">
 <package-header>
       <div>Header 1</div>
  </package-header>
  <div>content Header 1</div>
  <package-header>
       <div>Header2</div>
  </package-header>
  <div>content Header2</div>  
   <package-header>
       <div>Header 3</div>
  </package-header>
  <div>content Header 3</div>    
 <div>
```

my **custom directive**

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('packageHeader', 
  ['$window', function($window) {            

    var stickies = [],
    scroll = function scroll() {    
      var header= angular.element(document.querySelector("#List"))[0];

      console.log("scroll _ scroll");
      angular.forEach(stickies, function($sticky, index) {            
        var sticky = $sticky[0],
        pos = $sticky.data('pos');

        if (pos <= header.pageYOffset) {
          console.log("scroll offset Y");
          var $next = stickies[index + 1],              
          next = $next ? $next[0] : null,
          npos = $next.data('pos');  

          $sticky.addClass("fixed");

          if (next && next.offsetTop >= npos - next.clientHeight)
            $sticky.addClass("absolute").css("top", npos - sticky.clientHeight + 'px');
        } else {
          console.log("scroll offset X");
          var $prev = stickies[index - 1],
          prev = $prev ? $prev[0] : null;

          $sticky.removeClass("fixed");

          if (prev && header.pageYOffset <= pos - prev.clientHeight)
            $prev.removeClass("absolute").removeAttr("style");
        }
      });
    },


    link = function($scope, element, attrs) {

      var sticky = element.children()[0],
        $sticky = angular.element(sticky);

      element.css('height', sticky.clientHeight + 'px');

      $sticky.data('pos', sticky.offsetTop);
      stickies.push($sticky);
    };

    angular.element(document.querySelector("#List"))
      .off('scroll', scroll)
      .on('scroll', scroll);

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      //sticky - getting from style sheet
      template: '<sticky ng-transclude></sticky>',
      link: link
    };
 }]);
```

**CSS**

```
package-header,
sticky {
 display: block;
 }
package-header{
 opacity:.8;
 }
package-header>sticky {
  background: #9aa2a8;
  line-height: 24px;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  }
 package-header>sticky.fixed {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 0;
    }
  package-header>sticky.fixed.absolute {
    position: absolute;
   }
```

Please help me to resolve my issue

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Did you get any exception? Explain a bit of information about what you have tried to achieve in the directive with some details...

Comment: attaching code which is workinng with $window object https://plnkr.co/edit/NGroNUJ47bAwhWeECtWH?p=preview  but i need this should work with #list div id .. so i have tried by adding angular.element(document.querySelector("#List"))[0]; instead of window element but not working.

Comment: The above code is working when I'm doing widow scroll but i need while doing scroll on the div element...

Comment: I have added `offsetTop` instead of `pageYOffset` but only first header is getting fixed at top